# different models as an input for a function

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, dart

i have a function that takes a model as an input and converts it into a json body, the problem is i have too many models to take as an input, so do i have to create a function for each of the models or is there a way to declare one function and call that to do the tasks.

```
static Future<bool> updateSchedules(ScheduleModel data) async {
final response = await client.put(
  Uri.parse('$mainAPI$scheduleAPI'),
  headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
  body: toJsonConversion(data),
);
print(data.arrivalDate);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

the first function.

```
static Future<bool> updateRoutes(RoutesModel data) async {

final response = await client.put(
  Uri.parse('$mainAPI$routesAPI'),
  headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
  body: toJsonConversion(data),
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
}
```

the second function.

```
static String toJsonConversion(ScheduleModel data) {
final jsonData = data.toJsonn();
return json.encode(jsonData);
}
```

is there a way to call any model to work for the function, or do i have to declare a function for every model.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can achieve this.

Using dynamic type

```
void main() {
  Animal animal = Animal('Lucky');
  Human human = Human('John', 'Smith');

  // Print Animal Json
  printJson(animal);

  // Print Human Json
  printJson(human);
}

class Animal {
  String name;
  Animal(this.name);
  Map toJson() => {'name': name};
}

class Human {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  Human(this.firstName, this.lastName);
  Map toJson() => {'firstName': firstName, 'lastName': lastName};
}

void printJson(dynamic model) {
  print(model.toJson());
}
```

Output:

```
{name: Lucky}
{firstName: John, lastName: Smith}
```

Explanation:

I have a function called `printJson()` that takes in a `dynamic` type. Having it as dynamic would mean the variable can be any data type, could be `Animal`, could be `Human`, or whatever you desire. I then call `model.toJson()` and it will call the `toJson()` of the object. This would be a simple solution but the downside is that, what if you pass in a model that does not have a `.toJson()` by accident? You will not know the issue until during run time because your IDE will not know because the variable is being treated dynamically.

Is there a better way? Yes. its called abstraction.

```
void main() {
  Animal animal = Animal('Lucky');
  Human human = Human('John', 'Smith');

  // Print Animal Json
  printJson(animal);

  // Print Human Json
  printJson(human);
}

class Animal implements IBaseModel{
  String name;
  Animal(this.name);
  Map toJson() => {'name': name};
}

class Human implements IBaseModel{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  Human(this.firstName, this.lastName);
  Map toJson() => {'firstName': firstName, 'lastName': lastName};
}

abstract class IBaseModel{
  Map toJson();
}

void printJson(IBaseModel model) {
  print(model.toJson());
}
```

Output:

```
{name: Lucky}
{firstName: John, lastName: Smith}
```

Explanation:
What i did this time is i have an `abstract` class called `IBaseModel`. The abstract class has a method `Map toJson()`. Realize that i have a method in my `IBaseModel` but the method has no body. Abstract classes is like a blueprint. `class Human implements IBaseModel`. Whats happening here is that Human class implements IBaseModel. Meaning that whatever method is present in the `IBaseModel` will now have to be overridden with its own functionality. In this case, each child class has to define its own `Map toJson()` method.

`printJson()` now takes in a `IBaseModel`. This would mean only any object that implements `IBaseModel` would only be allowed to be passed into the method. This would prevent you from accidentally passing in an object that does not have the method `toJson()`. More info about `abstract` classes in dart https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/abstract-classes-in-dart/

Answer (score 1):

you need to define converter for each model.

there are many tools to create a complete dart model with converter methods from a json so you don't need to write it on you own like

https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

or different plugins on Android Studio or VsCode